# [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]Type' is not a subtype of type 'DownloadOptions'

Tags: google-drive-api

I downloaded a file from Drive correctly but the problem came after release, giving me the following error in console:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'DownloadOptions' of 'downloadOptions'

the other functions like upload file and list file works fine,

please help.

my code:

```
Future<void>_descargaArchivo(context, filename, fileId, driveApi ) async {

    final drive = GoogleDrive();

    final directory =  (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    var filedestino = File('$directory/VehiculosDB2.db');
    
    //descargar archivo
    drive.download(filedestino, fileId, driveApi, context);
   
  }
```